# Using the RSpec before suite hook with a tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2

I'm trying to use the Rspec before(:suite) hook with a tag like so:

```
  config.before(:suite, :selenium => true) do
    #magical awesomeness
  end
```

but Rspec doesn't seem to respect the tag and runs the code I only want to run with : selenium => true regardless.

The weird part is that I'm doing a very similar thing with the :each hook as well and that seems to work fine:

```
  config.around(:each, :selenium => true) do |example|
    Capybara.using_wait_time(10) do
      Capybara.using_driver(:selenium) do
        example.run
      end
    end
  end
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
if config.inclusion_filter[:selenium]
  config.before(:suite) do
    #magical awesomeness
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that it's useful to change configuration depending on commandline option `--tag`. With `rspec spec --tag selenium`, `config.inclusion_filter[:selenium]` returns true.

Comment: This does not work for me. I think before :suite is run before any tags are interpreted.

Answer (score 2):

I've not looked deeply into it, but my guess is that the :suite scope may be run before any tags are interpreted.  As far as I can think, you'd only want one :suite anyway (although I can see the use in your example).  I think it's possible to do a before :all that would do the same thing, so long as you put it "high" enough, like say in your spec_helper.rb?

==EDIT==

So I thought about it some more, and a solution that poped into my head was something like this:

```
# spec_helper.rb
# run with the tag :selenium => true when you set your env var RUN_SELENIUM like so:
# %> RUN_SELENIUM=1 bundle exec rspec spec/
config.filter_run_excluding :selenium => true if ENV['RUN_SELENIUM'].nil?

# now your before suite hook can be something along the lines of
config.before(:suite) do
  if ENV['RUN_SELENIUM'].nil?
    ## regular awesomeness
  else
    ## magical awesomeness
  end
end
```

I did a similar thing to handle tags using guard and guard-spec.  You can, of course, use the env var without the filter_run_excluding, and that would be the same as:
    %> RUN_SELENIUM=1 bundle exec rspec --tag selenium spec/
Adding the config line just helps keep it consistent.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey Poopinpants (awesome name btw), Yep the RSpec Core docs state "Warning: before(:suite, :with => :conditions)

The conditions hash is used to match against specific examples. Since before(:suite) is not run in relation to any specific example or group, conditions passed along with :suite are effectively ignored." http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/master/RSpec/Core/Hooks However, using a before(:all) in the spec_helper doesn't runs the magical awesomeness several times in a whole suite run so it's not exactly what I'm looking for.